# Getting error "Unknown property 'Product2StandardController.imageURL'" trying to access property from standard controller extension class

Tags: apex, visualforce, images

This is a follow up to my previous question here: [How to add an "Upload Image" button to an object that automatically inserts the URL of the image into a field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/194130/how-to-add-an-upload-image-button-to-an-object-that-automatically-inserts-the)

I am trying to add a file upload widget to the Product2 object that stores the uploaded file URL in a rich text field.

I received the following answer from the user Hemant Jain:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/194146/49567

I am not clear on the details of how this should be implemented, but I assume it is a widget that is embedded in the Product page layout. To embed a visualforce widget into a page layout, you must use the standard controller for that object. However, to add a custom method like that, you need to extend the standard controller with an extension class.

I ran into some issues trying to use this code and made some modifications to resolve the errors (see my comments on the answer) and also replaced the JQuery in the Visualforce page with vanilla javascript. However, I am now getting the error "Unknown property 'Product2StandardController.imageURL'" in my Visualforce page.

Here is my Apex extension class:

```
public class ProductPhotosExtension {
    private final Product2 prod;

    public ProductPhotosExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.prod = (Product2)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference upload() {
        String theURL = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('theURL');
        theURL = theURL.substring(theURL.indexOf(',') +1);

        Blob encodedBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(theURL);

        Document document = new Document();
        document.body = encodedBlob;

        document.AuthorId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        document.FolderId = 'the id of our product photos folder';
        document.Name = prod.Name;

        try {
            insert document;
            String imageURL = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';
            imageURL = imageURL + document.id;
        } catch (DMLException e) { ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Error uploading file')); return null;
        }

        finally { document.body = null; document = new Document(); }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Product2" extensions="ProductPhotosExtension">
    <input id="fileImageId" type="file" accept="image/*"/>

    <apex:actionFunction name="callUploadMethod" action="{!upload}"
                         oncomplete="fillRichTextArea('{!imageURL}')">
        <apex:param name="theURL" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>

    <div id="waitMessage" style="display: none">
        Please wait...
    </div>

    <script>
        var input_div = document.getElementById('fileImageId');
        var wait_div = document.getElementById('waitMessage');
        input_div.onchange(function(event) {
            var file = event.target.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
                dataurl = event.target.result;
                wait_div.style.display = 'block';
                callUploadMethod(dataurl);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });

        function fillRichTextArea(imageURL) {
            var heightValue = "375";
            var widthValue = "500";
            for(var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
                CKEDITOR.instances[i].insertHtml(
                    "<img src='" + imageURL + "' height='" + heightValue + 
                    " width=" + widthValue + "'/>"
                );
            wait_div.style.display = 'none';
        }                
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

If I remove `oncomplete="fillRichTextArea('{!imageURL}')"`, I get the error "(under ) must occur between tags."

I am not sure how to fix this problem. Some feedback on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the error message is because there is no controller property with a public getter named `imageURL`

Comment: OK, I added `private String imageURL;` to the top of the contents of my ProductPhotosExtension class, removed the `String` prefix from the imageURL reference in the try/catch block, and added a public getter method `public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }`
Now I get the error "(under ) must occur between tags" in my VF page. Not sure what this error means or how to fix. Please advise.

Comment: Your comment is unclear, probably some of your formatting disappeared. I think you need to have `apex:actionFunction` tag inside `apex:form` tag, is that it?

Comment: Yeah, that solved the error. Thank you. The VF page and Apex controller are saving without errors now. Looks like the answer Hemant Jain gave me was incomplete and was (is?) missing some code. There's a few issues with the javascript I need to work out. I made a mistake, `input_div.onchange(function(event) {` should be `input_div.onchange = function(event) {`.

Comment: Yeah. It all saves fine but it doesn't actually work. I need it to take the uploaded image, save it in the Documents object and then insert the URL into the field, but it's not doing that. The widget embeds fine and I'm able to click "browse" and add a file, but nothing happens after that. When I refresh the page the rich text field is still blank. It seems like the code snippet he posted was part of some larger implementation and I don't know how he had it working. Looks like its back to the drawing board...

Comment: I wish I knew how to better format code blocks in comments, but I don't know if the site actually lets you do that. It seems to strip out newlines which makes the code difficult to read. It also greatly limits the number of characters per comment which makes posting the changes I made to my code difficult

Comment: I posted the latest revisions of my Apex controller and VF page on pastebin, hopefully that will be easier to read (unfortunately no syntax highlighting, though) https://pastebin.com/4rHMWvPq

Comment: I am still not quite understanding why people keep suggesting I use a rich text field, either. All I need is to store the file in the documents object and store the path (not the image itself, just the url) in a plain text URL field. All these solutions seem incredibly convoluted for what I'm trying to do. To be clear: I have already built a separate VF page that renders the images based on those paths. All I need is a widget that can be accessed from the product layout to insert images into the Documents object (not the products object), and then get their PATH into a text field

Comment: Well I just wanted to post an update here. I ended up rolling my own custom solution which does not use rich text fields at all. You can see my solution here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/194687/49567

I am curious to know what folks more experienced with Salesforce think of this, as I am not really an expert on VF or Apex and am sure I did some things inelegantly. I am just curious to know how this solution stacks up against the ones that were suggested using the rich text fields.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the variable like this -

```
public String imageURL {get;set;}
```

I think this should be helpful for you